# Empty Space below the bottom bar in android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-bottomnav, bottombar

[image]
Hi Guys 
In my project trying to implement Bottom Navigation with navigation drawer
but after implementation, getting some empty space below bottom bar

any one idea on this, i struck here. help me

for Bottom Navigation i am using this
https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar

```
xml code:
Main.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/black"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/black">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/nav_header_main" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"></ListView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>][1]][1]
```

app_bar_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.nisum.homeScreen.HomeActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/myScrollingContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:bb_activeTabColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        app:bb_behavior="underNavbar|shy"
        app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottombar_tabs_three"
        app:bb_titleTextAppearance="@style/CustomTitleTextAppearance" />


<!--    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        </FrameLayout>-->


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

bottombar_tabs_three.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tabs>
    <tab
        id="@+id/tab_favorites"
        icon="@drawable/ic_favorites"
        title="Favorites" />
    <tab
        id="@+id/tab_nearby"
        icon="@drawable/ic_nearby"
        title="Nearby" />
    <tab
        id="@+id/tab_friends"
        icon="@drawable/ic_friends"
        title="Friends" />
</tabs>
```

Comment: show this @xml/bottombar_tabs_three file too.

Comment: have you changed **android:layout_height="60dp"** to **wrap_content** and tried ?

Comment: @AniruddhParihar filed adde thx

Comment: @AmitVaghela tried wrap_content no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove app:bb_behavior="underNavbar" from your xml